# Append stylesheet link for printing triggered on jQuery click() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one css link on the head section that has `media='screen'` attribute, then I want to link the other css file that has `media='print'` attribute dynamically.

and I do this for the solution.

```
$("div#alert").click(function(){
    $('head')
    .append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/alert.css' media='print' />");
    window.print();
});
```

But.. When I ran that code, the output just printed based on the `media='screen'` css.

Then I try again with the same code, I clicked the div element and when the print dialog box appear, I clicked the cancel button, then I clicked the div element again.. then clicked the ok button this time.. the `media='print'` is working... So what do I have to do with the `window.print()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are calling window.print() too early (before the print stylesheet has even been downloaded) - try this:

```
$("div#alert").click(function(){
    $('head')
    .append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/alert.css' media='print' />");
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.print();
    }, 1000);
});
```

A more elegant solution would be to load the stylesheet asynchronously, insert it in the head, and then call the print() function in the callback of the AJAX request.

Comment: Doing ajax request is too much.. I thought the `deferred.then()` would work, but `setTimeout` is fine, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.get` and the `success callback` in this way:

```
$("div#alert").click(function(){
    $.get('css/alert.css', function (response) {
       $('head')
          .append("<style rel='stylesheet' media='print'></style>")
          .html(response);

    }).success(function () { 
        window.print();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your javascript function is running and not letting the browser in to update the CSS.

Watch [this video](http://yuilibrary.com/theater/douglas-crockford/crockford-loopage/) that explains how event loop works in Javasript. That also means that if your cycles work slowly and block the browser, you can just split them in timeouts.

My advice will be doing something like Alex is telling, to put `.print` in a timeout.