# Dynamically add contents style to CKEditor 4 instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor

I have passed a CSS filepath to my CKEditor instance with the `contentsCss` option, which works great.  However, I need to be able dynamically add more styles that I can't add in the CSS file.  In version 3 it looks like one could use the `addCss` function ([see this forum post](http://ckeditor.com/comment/40761)).  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in version 4 ([see this forum post](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/addCss-Method-on-editor-object-in-4.0)).  Does anyone have an alternative? I am using the jQuery adapter, so a solution using either API would work.

Comment: if you have jquery you can use css function `.css('height','23px')` or addClass function `.addClass('large')`

Comment: @SethMcClaine Can I use the `.css` function to apply a print style?

Comment: check this guy out, let me know if it helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765866/append-stylesheet-link-for-printing-triggered-on-jquery-click-event

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230376/how-can-i-apply-a-media-print-style-to-a-ckeditor-instance/19231561#19231561. Also [`CKEDITOR.dom.appendStylesheet()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.document-method-appendStyleSheet) may do the trick for you if you want a plain (e.g. non-media) stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like

```
$(window).on('print',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var styles = '<style>'+/*calculation of styles*/+'</style>'
  $('head').append(styles);
  window.print();

});
```

or

```
$(window).on('load',function(e){
  var styles = '<style>'+/*calculation of media query print styles*/+'</style>'
  $('head').append(styles);

});
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because I tell CKEditor which CSS file to use via JavaScript.  It doesn't use any styles on the page.